# Search User inputted string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to implement a simple string search. I have a Book model which has bookname, isbn, authname as attributes. I have added this at the end of my index.html.haml to allow the user to search for a book using isbn.

```
=form_tag({controller: "books_controller", action: "searchbook"}, :method => :get) do
  .search_field
    =text_field_tag :q
    =button_tag 'Go' , class: 'search-button' , type: :submit
%br
```

Added this to my book_controller.rb

```
def searchbook
    @searchedbook = Book.where(isbn: q)
end
```

Added this to my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :courses

  resources :books

  get 'books_controller/searchbook' => 'books_controller#searchbook'
end
```

After running rails server when I go to http://localhost:3000/books I get a list of all the books. I can see the input box at the end of list and when I enter an isbn number to search for the book, this is the error that I get:

```
uninitialized constant BooksControllerController
```

When I run rake routes I see the route in the list:

```
books_controller_searchbook GET    /books_controller/searchbook(.:format) books_controller#searchbook
```

I am not sure what went wrong there. All I want to do is take the user inputted string and run the Book.where(isbn: "userinput") query to find the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what's the error `uninitialized constant BooksControllerController`, this means it already knowing that 'books' is a controller, but you have specified `books_controller` so it is becoming `BooksControllerController`

Actually you don't have to specify the controller string

Try this

```
 get 'books/searchbook' => 'books#searchbook'
```

Or

```
match 'searchbook', to: 'books#searchbook', via: :get
```

Comment: I tried this:  get 'books/searchbook' => 'books#searchbook'
I got this error:  ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Books#index
No route matches {:action=>"searchbook", :controller=>"books_controller"}

and when I try this:match 'searchbook', to: 'books#searchbook', via: :get


I get this:  NoMethodError in Books#index
 undefined method `match' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f453f1a38>:0x007f9f487aaa50>

Comment: @neesop - again you are making the same mistake, in your form also remove controller string `=form_tag({controller: "books_controller", action: "searchbook"}, :method => :get) do` make it like `=form_tag({controller: "books", action: "searchbook"}, :method => :get) do`

Comment: Yes!! You were absolutely right. That fixed my problem. But now I get a new error which says: 

NameError in BooksController#searchbook

undefined local variable or method `q' for #<BooksController:0x007f9f48329ad0>

So if you see my searchbook function in the controller it uses the user input 'q' as the parameter. Why do I still get undefined variable for 'q'. Also, how do I access the user's input and set it equal to q ? Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you for your help @sontya!

Comment: when you pass some value from form, it becomes the params, which is a `Hash`. So you can do `@searchedbook = Book.where(isbn: params[:q])`